# C++, why is an increase in one element of a multi-dimensional array appear to be increasing another?

Tags: c++, arrays

This may not be elegant. Chiefly because I am relatively new to C++, but this little program I am putting together is stumbling here.

I don't get it. Have I misunderstood arrays? The edited code is:

```
int diceArray [6][3][1] = {};

...

}else if (y >= xSuccess || x >= xSuccess){

// from here...

    diceArray[2][1][0] = diceArray[2][1][0] + 1;
    diceArray[2][1][1] = diceArray[2][1][1] + 1;

// ...to here, diceArray[2][2][0] increases by 1. I am not referencing that part of the array at all. Or am I?

}
```

By using comments I tracked the culprit down to the second expression. If I comment out the first one `diceArray[2][2][0]` does not change.

Why is `diceArray[2][1][1] = diceArray[2][1][1] + 1` causing `diceArray[2][2][0]` to increment?

I tried..

```
c = diceArray[2][1][1] + 1;

diceArray[2][1][1] = c;
```

..as a workaround but it was just the same. It increased `diceArray[2][2][0]` by one.

Comment: which `if` you are using `else` for? add code

Comment: `diceArray[6][3][1]` means that the 3rd index of your array has only 1 element. `diceArray[2][1][1]` is accessing the second element from an index with only 1.

Comment: The third dimension of `diceArray` is `1`.   Your code uses values `0` and `1` to index values in the third dimension.   That is running one too far.

Answer (score 11):

You are indexing out of bounds. If I declare such an array

```
int data [3];
```

Then the valid indices are

```
data[0]
data[1]
data[2]
```

The analog to this is that you declare

```
int diceArray [6][3][1]
                     ^
```

But then try to assign to

```
diceArray[2][1][0]
                ^

diceArray[2][1][1]     // This is out of range
                ^
```

Since you are assigning out of range, due to pointer arithmetic you are actually assigning to the next dimension due to striding, etc.

Comment: Aha! Okay, so I just need to increase the array size. Some kind of hold over from my VB6 days perhaps. I will try it right now.

Comment: @DJones: Accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

The variable is declared as:

```
int diceArray [6][3][1] = {};
```

This is how it looks like in memory:

```
+---+                       -.
|   |  <- diceArray[0][0]     \
+---+                          \
|   |  <- diceArray[0][1]       > diceArray[0]
+---+                          /
|   |  <- diceArray[0][2]     /
+---+                       -'
|   |  <- diceArray[1][0]     \
+---+                          \
|   |  <- diceArray[1][1]       > diceArray[1]
+---+                          /
|   |  <- diceArray[1][2]     /
+---+                       -'
  .            .                      .
  .            .                      .
  .            .                      .
+---+                       -.
|   |  <- diceArray[5][0]     \
+---+                          \
|   |  <- diceArray[5][1]       > diceArray[5]
+---+                          /
|   |  <- diceArray[5][2]     /
+---+                       -'
```

The innermost component of `diceArray` is an array of size `1`.
`C`/`C++` arrays are always indexed starting from `0` and that means the only valid index in and array of size `1` is `0`.

During the compilation, a reference to `diceArray[x][y][z]` is converted using pointer arithmetic to offset `x*3*1+y*1+z` (`int` values) using the memory address of `diceArray` as base.

The code:

```
diceArray[2][1][1] = diceArray[2][1][1] + 1;
```

operates on offset `8 (=2*3*1+1*1+1)` inside `diceArray`. The same offset is computed using `diceArray[2][2][0]`, which is a legal access inside the array.

The modern compilers are usually able to detect this kind of errors and warn you on the compilation.